# Malloc y wcscpy: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED

Tags: c, punteros, winapi

Estoy tratando de crear y utilizar un puntero a una cadena y unirlo con otro puntero de cadena reservado con `malloc`, pero siempre obtengo este mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    LPWSTR str1 = L"Software\\WinSide\\";
    LPWSTR str2 = (LPWSTR)malloc(wcslen(str1)+1);
    wcscpy(str2, str1);


    if (str2 == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"Malloc error.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Result= %s\n", str2);
    }

    free(str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Si yo pongo un valor en `malloc` grande como 50, por ejemplo, funciona bien. Sé que el problema está en la asignación de memoria, pero no entiendo por qué.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

**Edito:**

Si utilizo los tipos de datos estándar de C, el programa funciona, pero no entiendo por qué. Agrego el código:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char * str1 = "Software\\WinSide\\";
    char * str2 = (char *)malloc(strlen(str1)+1);
    strcpy(str2, str1);

    if (str2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Malloc error.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Result= %s\n", str2);   

    }

    free(str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con snprintf? A mí algunas veces me funciona mejor que utilizar mallocs para strings.. y puedes darle tamaño.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin tener experiencia en Windows, veo que en tu código reservas **1 byte** al final de la cadena, para almacenar el final de la misma.

```
LPWSTR str2 = (LPWSTR)malloc(wcslen(str1)+1);
wcscpy(str2, str1);
/*wcscat(str2, argv[1]);*/
DWORD size = wcslen(str1)+1;
```

Sin embargo, usas cadenas L, con caracteres anchos. No recuerdo el tamaño exacto ni el tipo concreto (wchar_t o similar), pero creo que Window usaba caracteres de 32 bits (4 bytes) para ese tipo de cadenas.

Prueba reservando 4 bytes, en lugar de uno:

```
malloc( wcslen( str1 ) + 4 );
```

Si recuerdo el tipo exacto, editaré la respuesta.

*postdata:* **no** mezcles tipos. Si usas cadenas anchas, usa caracteres anchos; si usas cadenas normales `char *` ( ¿LPSTR en Windows ? ), entonces usa caracteres normales ( sizeof( char ) )

EDITO

Es wchar_t; por lo tanto, lo correcto sería

```
LPWSTR str2 = (LPWSTR)malloc(wcslen(str1)+sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Es un error común, confundir **bytes** con **caracteres**.

`malloc()` trabaja con **bytes**.
`char *str = "hola";` es un array de **caracteres** que, casualmente, tienen un tamaño de 1 byte.
`wchar_t *str2 = L"adios";` es un array de **caracteres** que **no** tienen porqué ser de 1 byte cada uno.

Si fuera posible utilizar `sizeof` con bloques de memória, tendríamos algo como esto:

```
sizeof( malloc( 100 ) )  -> 100
sizeof( "hola" )         -> 5 ( 4 caracteres de 1 byte, mas 1 caracter de terminador de la cadena.
sizeof( L"adios" )       -> depende de la arquitectura, el sistema, etc. Como se vió en el problema, puede ser perfectamente de 48 bytes ( 5 caracteres * 4 bytes cada uno, + 1 caracter (otros 4 bytes) de terminador de la cadena.
```

Además de lo anterior, las *funciones* que trabajan con cadenas están *preparadas* y *especializadas* en el tipo de cadenas que usan. Por eso, `strcpy()` añade **1 byte** al final, mientras que `wcpcpy()` añade un **caracter ancho** (4 o mas bytes) al final.

**Conclusión**: no asumir tamaños, usar el `sizeof` (que está desde los inicios del lenguaje, por algo será), no mezclar tipos, y usar las funciones adecuadas para cada uno.

Comment: En realidad ese byte de más es para el caracter `\0`, que indica el final de la cadena. Probé igual con 4, pero nada. Como te digo, si uso 50, por ejemplo, funciona. Se supone que el `wcslen` me debería traer el tamaño exacto de la cadena. Ahora, no pienses tanto en Windows por los tipos de datos, haz de cuenta que estoy usando `wchar_t *` en vez de `LPWSTR`.

Comment: Es imposible no pensar en Windows si solo usas funciones de su API. prueba usando funciones de la librería C estandar, tales como strlen, memcpy y similares.

Comment: No entiendo lo de mezclar tipos, pues creo que estoy usando todos los que corresponden a la API. Ahora, cambié a los tipos de datos estándar y funcionó. ¿Por qué? Editaré la pregunta para comparar.

Comment: ¿ De donde sacas que las cadenas **de caracteres anchos** no se terminan con un caracter **igualmente ancho** para indicar su fin ? Mezclas cadenas de **caracteres anchos** con **bytes** para indicar el final.

Comment: El tema es que agregando 4 también falla.

Comment: Es que no recuerdo el tipo exacto. **Seguro** que poniendo `malloc( wcslen( str1 ) + sizeof( *tipo_exacto* ) )` funciona. Estamos suponiendo que un caracter ancho son 4 bytes pero, ¿ y si por eficiencia, se usan 8 bytes ? ¿ estas en arquitecturas de 64 bits ?

Comment: Así funciona, Trauma, pero entonces estaría reservando es todo un vector, ¿no? Aunque, ciertamente, el problema sí está en mi definición.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48247/discussion-between-trauma-and-checho).